# JS Plugin to fix notchy page scrolling on Windows?

Tags: javascript, html, user-experience

I've seen some sites that "normalize" the erratic scroll wheel behavior on Windows machines, but I haven't been able to find a library that addresses it. This behavior is especially problematic on sites that use Skrollr, because the mousewheel almost completely breaks the immersion of the animations.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go!

http://bassta.bg/2013/05/smooth-page-scrolling-with-tweenmax/

The nice thing about this is that it is very modular - you'll be able to add it into your code without making any other changes.